# How to run job at certain time and then repeat after that time

Tags: node.js, agenda

i want to send a notification for my users and I need check users states everyday and each user that get this situation send him/her notif. 
for this purpose i use agenda.js library. 
when I run this code i want to create a job Once and after that repeat call this job. so for this i write this code:

```
  const job = await agenda.create(SCHEDULE_MISS_YOU_NOTIF, data)
  job.repeatEvery('40 16 * * *', { timezone: 'Asia/Tehran' })
  await job.save()
```

but my problem is every time i run this code, immediately i get a notif and after that i get notif on time that scheduled. how can i remove first one notif and why this notif occure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
job.repeatEvery('40 16 * * *', {
  skipImmediate: true,
  timezone: 'Asia/Tehran'
});
```